# Why doesn't $.get Url.Action reach ASP.NET MVC async Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to call my ASP.NET MVC 5 controller `AdminController.cs` method below:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<RegionalDealerships> RegionalAvailability(string region)
{
    var model = await RetailActivityModelData.RegionalAvailabilityAsync(region, ViewBag.Library);
    return View(model);
}
```

In my Razor page, this is triggered by the dropdown, and fires the Javascript:

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("RegionalAvailability", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    <label>
        Region:@Html.DropDownListFor(
               m => m.Region,
               Model.Regions,
               new { @onchange = "updateForm('2')" })
    </label>
}
---
<script>
    const updateForm = (changeElement) => {
        let region = document.getElementById("Region");
        console.log('changeElement=' + changeElement);
        if (changeElement === '2') {
            if (0 < region.value.length) {
                console.log('region=' + region.value);
                $.get("@Url.Action("RegionalAvailability", "Admin")?region=" + region.value);
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Debugging with Chrome's DevTools, I can see on the Console tab that I am getting into the call:

[image: DevTools screenshot]

However, my breakpoint is not being reached in the C# code.

I don't see any errors. How would I debug this? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have [HttpPost] attribute, but trying to reach it using a Get, to fix it just remove [HttpPost]

```
public async Task<RegionalDealerships> RegionalAvailability(string region)
```

And I don't know why your view has a form with a post acton too. You have to select somethig one.